# python assigning key to dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to assign key to dict without value. So i want to assign date to the dict

here my current code

```
desc_date = {}

date = ' '.join(line_of_list[0:2])
if desc_date.has_key(date):
    # Not sure how to assign date to desc_date now
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you intend to do with the dict?

Comment: i am going to be putting 2 keys and 1 values to print.

Comment: currenty got this but aint working any help   if desc_ip.has_key(date):
            desc_ip['a'] = 0 
            desc_ip['b'] = 0
            desc_ip['a']+=1
print desc_ip

Comment: You are confused. `desc_date` starts empty, so has_key will be false, so none of the other code will run. What is the relationship between the date and the 'a' and 'b' keys? What are you trying to do?

Comment: basically what i want to do is find the date which is already done in the code and then i was to assign the date to the dict so dict will look like this then {feb, 8, jan 10}

Answer (score 4):

Checking for the existence of a key is really simple:

```
if date in desc_date:
  # Yep, the key exists
```

You'd have to use a placeholder value if you want to make it "look" empty:

```
desc_date[date] = None # Or [] if you'll be storing multiple items per key.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Either use a `set` instead, or use a "fake" value such as `None`.